# How to find the minimum value of the function $f=\sin\theta_1 + \sin\theta_2$, where $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi = π.$

Tags: functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

> How to find the minimum value of the function $f=\sin\theta_1 +$
>   $\sin\theta_2$, where $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi = π,$ where $\phi$ is a variable such that $0 < \phi < π$

we can easily do the substitution $\theta_1 =π - \theta_2 - \phi$, and take the derivative of the $f$ and find the critical value of $f$, but when we are doing that, we have to also need to know that $\dfrac {\mathrm d \phi}{\mathrm d \theta_1}$, so how can we solve this problem ?

Edit:Basically $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\phi$ are the inner angle of a triangle which is created by connecting a point on an ellipse to the focus of that ellipse, and $\phi$ is the angle that sees the major axis of the ellipse, and I want to find the minimum value of $sin\theta_1 + sin\theta_2$.

Comment: The minimal value of $f$ is $-2$, for $\theta_1 = -\pi/2 +2k_1\pi$ and $\theta_2 = -\pi/2 +2k_2\pi$, $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $\phi$ is a variable, its value is just obtained from the constraint $\phi = \pi- \theta_1-\theta_2$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $\phi$ is a variable.

Comment: @AlexSilva In order for me to understand your solution, you have to give me a clear solution.

Comment: @AlexSilva you are aware that there is a constraint for the values of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, right ?

Comment: @Leth, your post is confusing. Is $\phi$ a function of $\theta_1$? Which are the "independent" variables here, and which are the functions that depend on them? What are the arguments of $f$?

Comment: @AlexM. Basically $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\phi$ are the inner angle of a triangle, and I want to find the minimum value of $sin\theta_1 + sin\theta_2$.

Comment: Again, you have changed the question. I have counted a lot of versions: (1) minimize $f$ with $\phi$ apparently constant. (2) $\phi$ is no more a constant. (3) $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$. (4) $0 < \phi < \pi$. (5) $\phi$, $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ are inner angles of a triangle. (6) Now, it is a maximization problem. (7) The triangle are constructed from an ellipse. What do you want????? Yet, the construction of the triangle from the ellipse is still not clear!! I give up!!

Comment: @AlexSilva First of all, I corrected that the question is a minimisation but some fellow friend is changed back.Secondly, I never said $\phi$ is constant.Thirdly, yes I made a typo by using $\leq$s so I correct, sorry about that.Fourthly, the fact that $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi =π$ is already says that they are the inner angle of a triangle.Finally, while I was writing the problem to the site, I just thought asking the mathematical part of the question, so I didn't gave the actual problem directly, but after the giving answer, I saw that I'm not describing the problem correctly, so ...

Comment: @AlexSilva .. so I gave the actual problem.

Comment: "the fact that $\theta_1 +\theta_2+ \phi= \pi$ is already says that they are the inner angle of a triangle."  You are so WRONG!!!  Take $\theta_1 = -\pi/2$, $\theta_2 = \pi$ and $\phi = \pi/2$.

Comment: @AlexSilva You are right, I hadn't thought it.

Answer (score 2):

$$ f=\sin(\theta_1) + \sin(\theta_2) $$

Constrained to $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi = \pi$ which also implies that $\theta_2=\pi-\phi-\theta_1$

$$ f(\theta_1)=\sin(\theta_1)+\sin(\pi-\phi-\theta_1)$$

$$ f(\theta_1)=\sin(\theta_1)+\sin(\pi-(\phi+\theta_1))$$

$$ f(\theta_1)=\sin(\theta_1)+\ \sin(\pi)\cos(\phi+\theta_1)-\cos(\pi)\sin(\phi+\theta_1)$$

$$ f(\theta_1)= \sin(\theta_1)+\sin(\phi+\theta_1)$$

$$ \frac{df}{d(\theta_1)} = \cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\phi+\theta_1)$$

For maxima/minima $ \frac{df}{d(\theta_1)}=0$

$$ \cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\phi+\theta_1) =0 $$

$$ 2\cos\left(\frac{2\theta_1+\phi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2} \right)=0$$

Clearly $ 2\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$ is a constant so

$$\cos\left(\frac{2\theta_1+\phi}{2}\right)=0$$

$$\left(\frac{2\theta_1+\phi}{2}\right) = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k $$

$$ 2\theta_1  +\phi = \pm \pi + 4\pi k $$

$$ \theta_1 =  \frac{1}{2}\left(\pm \pi + 4\pi k - \phi \right)$$

Let $k=0$  then $\theta_1= \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \phi)$

Subbing this back into $f$

$$ f(\theta_1) = \sin(\theta_1)+\sin(\phi+\theta_1)$$

$$ f(\theta_1)= \sin\left( \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \phi)\right) + \sin \left( \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \phi)+\phi \right) $$

$$ f(\theta_1)= \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\phi}{2}\right) + \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\phi}{2} \right) $$

$$ f(\theta_1)= 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cos \left(\frac{-\phi}{2} \right) $$

$$ f(\theta_1)_{\text{max}} = 2\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right) $$

Note that you do not need to know $\dfrac {\mathrm d \phi}{\mathrm d \theta_1}$ to solve the problem since $\phi$ is a constant and not a function.

Comment: when you take the derivative of f respect to $\theta_1$ how do you know that $\frac{d(\phi + \theta1) }{d\theta_1} = 1$ ? that is the main point of my question actually.

Comment: @Leth, when we differentiate with respect to $\theta_1$, other variables are treated as constants

Comment: @AlexSilva wouldn't it just be a number tho?

Comment: @AlexSilva Actually, $\phi$ in the function $f$ is a independent variable, but we are just giving a contrasting for the independent variables by saying $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi = π$.

Comment: @dydxx but still it doesn't give me an answer since the answer depends on the given $\phi$, which I don't have one because if I found the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that I'm look for, I would know $\phi$

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x,y,x+y\in (0,\pi)$

\begin{align*}
  f(x,y) &= \sin x+\sin (\pi-x-y) \\
  &= \sin x+\sin(x+y) \\
  &= 2\cos \frac{y}{2} \sin \left( \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x+y}{2} \right) \\
  &\ge 0
\end{align*}

**Case I**

$$\cos \dfrac{y}{2}=0 \implies y=\pi$$
which is beyond the domain.

**Case II**

$$\sin \left( x+\dfrac{y}{2} \right)=0 \implies \dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x+y}{2}=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \pi$$
which is also beyond the domain.

> Can only approach to zero when $(\theta_1,\phi)=(x,y)=(0^{+},0^{+})$, $(0^{+},\pi^{-})$ or $(\pi^{-},0^{+})$

Comment: where is $\phi$ in the first step ?

Comment: $$\sin \theta_1+\sin \theta_2=\sin \theta_1+\sin (\pi-\theta_1-\phi)$$ using $x=\theta_1$ and $y=\phi$ for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this geometrically. i will take $x = \cos t, y = \sin t$ on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ with $t$ the arc length. the constraint $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \phi = \pi$ can be turne into $$\frac{\theta_1 + \theta_2}2 = \pi/2 - \phi/2 \tag 1$$  look at the radial line $l: t = \pi/2 - \phi/2,$  the constraint (1) implies that the midpoint of the secant line 
$(\cos \theta_1, \sin \theta_1) \mbox{ and } (\cos \theta_2, \sin \theta_2)$ is on $l.$ the lowest of $l$ has coordinates $(-\sin(\phi/2), -\cos(\phi/2)).$  the minimum of $-sin \theta_1 + \sin \theta_2$ is twice the $y$ coordinate of the lowest point; that is $-2 \cos (\phi/2).$

Comment: But I don't have a numerical value for $\phi$, so how can I find the min $\theta_1$ and $theta_2$ ?

Comment: i was assuming that $\theta_1, \theta_2$ range over $[0, 2\pi];$  otherwise the global minimum will depend on the range of $\theta_1, \theta_2.$  you can see that how the midpoint slides on that radial line.

Comment: no they are in $[0,π]$

Comment: minimum is $-2 \cos \phi/2 \sin \phi/2 = -\sin \phi.$

Comment: but still I don't have a numerical value for $\phi$.